# Using New-MailboxSearch on Exchange Online

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have to migrate my scripts to Exchange Online.

One of my scripts uses `New-MailboxSearch` cmdlet. [According to
Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298064(v=exchg.160).aspx):

> On July 1, 2017, you'll no longer be able to use the
>   New-MailboxSearch cmdlet to create In-Place eDiscovery searches and
>   In-Place Holds in Exchange Online. To create eDiscovery searches and
>   eDiscovery case holds, please start using New-ComplianceSearch and
>   New-CaseHoldPolicy in the Office 365 Security & Compliance Center.
>   You'll still be able to use Set-MailboxSearch to modify existing
>   In-Place eDiscovery searches and In-Place Holds. Creating new searches
>   and holds in Exchange Server 2013 will still be supported, and
>   searches run from your on-premises organization in an Exchange hybrid
>   deployment aren't affected by this change.

I understand that I must use `New-ComplianceSearch` cmdlet to permform the searchs.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Microsoft will change the way how such searches can be done (as quoted by your posting and as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298064(v=exchg.160).aspx) by Microsoft as well). However Microsoft postponed the deadline and come up with a better explanation as outlined by you, which can be found [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/eDiscovery-in-Office-365-143b3ab8-8cb0-4036-a5fc-6536d837bfce?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US):

> Note: We've postponed the July 1, 2017 deadline for creating new
>   In-Place eDiscovery searches in Exchange Online (in Office 365 and
>   Exchange Online standalone plans). But later this year or early next
>   year, you won't be able to create new searches in ExchangeOnline. To
>   create eDiscovery searches, please start using the Content Search page
>   in the O365ComplianceCenter. After we decommission new In-Place
>   eDiscovery searches, you'll still be able to modify existing In-Place
>   eDiscovery searches. In Exchange hybrid deployments, searches run from
>   your on-premises organization won't be affected by this change.

This might explain why you still can use this feature and which results in your question. However You need to switch to there new way to perform this action in the future and therefore you need to start using the [New-ComplianceSearch](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210905(v=exchg.160).aspx) when running Exchange online (this change will not affect Exchange 2016 on Premises yet).

Its mostly due to the reason that such "features" are moved into the "Office 365 Security & Compliance Center".

*Keep noted that not every Office 365 plan included every feature from the "Office 365 Security & Compliance Center" as written [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn933793.aspx) (Especially 'eDiscovery export' or 'Advanced eDiscovery' isn´t part from every Office 365 plan).*

Comment: It would not be more reasonable (despite Microsoft's recommendations) to use the Search-Mailbox cmdlet?

Comment: That depends a little bit what you wish to perform with your script.

Comment: My objective is made a search on multiples emails accounts and store it in another email account. Later I need to retrieve and edit information of this searches

Comment: I think is not possible retrieve and edit previous serches if I use Search-Mailbox cmdlet. Am I right?